# UITapRecognizer: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: uitapgesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I got the following error: unrecognized selector sent to instance
and found a lot of solutions that didn't work for me. I create the the object from a view class. I tap the imageview and then i got the error

I have the following code:

```
@implementation MyTappableImage

@synthesize myImageView, myRect, isTapped, myTap;

- (id)initWithRect:(CGRect) myRect2
{ 
myRect = &myRect2;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"hert.png"];
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:*myRect];
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myImageView setImage:image];
isTapped = NO;
myTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:myTap];
return self;
}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
NSLog(@"druk");
}
```

Comment: You need to update your question with the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

You neglect to call `[super initWithRect:]` or any other super `init`. Per Apple's documentation (emphasis added):

> An object isn’t ready to be used until it has been initialized. The
>   init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it
>   simply returns self.
>
> **In a custom implementation of this method, you must invoke super’s designated initializer then initialize and return the new object**. If
>   the new object can’t be initialized, the method should return nil.

Since you are failing to do something that **must** be done you should expect undefined behaviour.

(EDIT: I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with `myRect` but as written it'll just be an invalid pointer as soon as you return).